# Get current location start point to uri to start navi

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I finally found out on how to add more locations to my route in uri:

Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/48.8276261,2.3350114/48.8476794,2.340595/48.8550395,2.300022/48.8417122,2.3028844"));
StartActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that I only see Preview button and not Start to start navigate. 
I think it's due to the fact that the first point is not the current location. 
Does anyone knows how to set up the first point as the starting point where I am currently, to have the possibility to start navigation?

Comment: Maybe `dir_action=navigate` and `waypoints` paramater is your want.Although this is not the same as normal navigation, the intent to open the navigation method can only do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the **dir_action=navigate** parameter setting will be close to what you want.

In the official Google Maps documentation, the section on ***Forming the Directions URL*** in [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) talks about how to navigate using Intent.There are ***dir_action=navigate*** and ***waypoints*** in parameters to set the navigation mode and intermediate waypoint settings. If you need to start from the user's starting point, then the ***origin*** parameter can be (original to most relevant starting location, such as user location, if available.)

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters
```

> **origin**: Defines the starting point from which to display directions. Defaults to most relevant starting location, such as user location, if available. If none, the resulting map may provide a blank form to allow a user to enter the origin.
>
> **dir_action=navigate** (optional): Launches either turn-by-turn navigation or route preview to the specified destination, based on whether the origin is available. If the user specifies an origin and it is not close to the user's current location, or the user's current location is unavailable, the map launches a route preview. If the user does not specify an origin (in which case the origin defaults to the user's current location), or the origin is close to the user's current location, the map launches turn-by-turn navigation. Note that navigation is not available on all Google Maps products and/or between all destinations; in those cases this parameter will be ignored.
>
> **waypoints**: Specifies one or more intermediary places to route directions through between the origin and destination. Multiple waypoints can be specified by using the pipe character (|) to separate places (for example, Berlin,Germany|Paris,France). The number of waypoints allowed varies by the platform where the link opens, with up to three waypoints supported on mobile browsers, and a maximum of nine waypoints supported otherwise. Waypoints are displayed on the map in the same order they are listed in the URL. Each waypoint can be either a place name, address, or comma-separated latitude/longitude coordinates. Strings should be URL-escaped, so waypoints such as "Berlin,Germany|Paris,France" should be converted to Berlin%2CGermany%7CParis%2CFrance.

Examples from your data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=48.8276261,2.3350114&destination=48.8417122,2.3028844&waypoints=48.8476794,2.340595|48.8550395,2.300022&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate"));
StartActivity(intent);
```

If want defaulf from current location:

Uri is : `"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=&destination=48.8417122,2.3028844&waypoints=48.8476794,2.340595|48.8550395,2.300022&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate"`

Here's an [official method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents) to help you test if your destination is within planning and automatically start from your current location：

```
Android.Net.Uri gmmIntentUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("google.navigation:q=48.8417122,2.3028844");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.SetPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
StartActivity(mapIntent);
```

You can modify `q=48.8417122,2.3028844` to your want test destination data.

If want to modify location of simulator , look at the screenshot below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ye but how to make origin to automaticly pick my location? I used the one from Pacyn's answer and it works however i only see the "Preview" button and not Start to start navigate, what to put in origin?

Comment: @Henry Not setting vaue for origin, like url is "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=&destination=48.8417122,2.3028844&waypoints=48.8476794,2.340595|48.8550395,2.300022&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate".And  If the user specifies an origin and it is not close to the user's current location, or the user's current location is unavailable, the map launches a route preview.You can refer to official document.

Comment: One what is missing is how to get value of current location? All my values like destination/waypoints will come from database however origin sould be taken somehow based on current loation, something like to say in code origin = GetCurrentLocationValues()

Comment: @Henry Sorry,I Misunderstood what you mean.If want to get location , need to use other way like GetCurrentLocationValues() in Xamrin Android.https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location

Comment: wow really so much code is required? What about intent? you mean i cannot use it or?

Comment: @Henry If you get the current location, just to use it in the intent, then origin=empty defaults to navigate from the user's current location. If you want to get the current location through the intent and use it elsewhere, then the intent can't be done.

Comment: so can you change your intent uri in your answer to make origin as default which woul mean current position then according to your input it should set first point (source) to defaults means current position right?

Comment: @Henry I have updated the answer.Note that If the current location and the waypoints or destination you set are too impractical, the path will not be planned successfully.

Comment: i get "No route found" using your uri. I checked if i add some value to origin then it works so it means origin= is not working

Comment: @Henry As explained above, if the waypoints and destinations are far from your current location, then the route is not found. I suggest you try the navigation near you to try it out.The destinations and waypoints I provide in the uri may not be appropriate for your current location.

Comment: @Henry You need to set reasonable waypoints and destinations. It is not necessarily reasonable to set the latitude and longitude provided by origin. The waypoints and destinations in the Uri I provide need to be modified to reasonable data for your current test location.If solved it ,  thanks for marking it in advance. :)

Comment: i set everything and got "Route not found" ... origin is as "origin=" all other waypoints and destination is real

Comment: @Henry You can support your current loacation, I will design a destination and some waypoints,then I will check it.Just like the origin data given in your question is the address in Paris. If your position is too far away, then this uri will not succeed.One thing to note is that the current location of the Google Maps in the emulator does not seem to be the same as the location on the PC page, not in one country.

Comment: So jow to make it works? The main target is to prepare route for driver: starting point has to be his real starting position, waypoints will be taken from database as well as destination. Application has to read driver start position and rest points will be taken from database. At the end finall uri has to be prepared and maps should be opened for driver with start button ready for driver to start navigation.

Comment: @Henry I mean the api data you took out and the current location of your test needs to determine if it is appropriate, you can provide your current location, I am trying to set a target location test. In addition, there is a new method in the answer, you can test it yourself.

Comment: You mean to test by deploying app on real phone and go out to test?

Comment: @ No , just you need set a reasonable destination to test.Not directly use api data,because your app will be used by customer finally .

Comment: and fire up normally on emulator?

Comment: @Henry Yeah,my local test is ok.

Comment: Jiang - MSFTT I used your code, put real numbers in my country, when android emulator opened i see google maps app opened with first starting point as "Your location" and destination as i gave but at the bottom i see "No route found". I've checked even if i put manually in opened maps destination it also show "No route found"

Comment: @Henry Okey,you first manually open your simulator and open the map app to see if the current location is displayed in your country.Before I tested it, the current location of the location on the simulator was in San Francisco, but this is not in my country, you need to check it out.

Comment: @Jiang - MSFTT lol you were right my current loaction is somwhere in the see of arabia... is it possible to change current location in android emulator?

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to change the current positioning of the simulator. So I can only find an address test near this location on the map.But if you have a physical device, you can use it for testing. =^= If answer be helpful ,thanks for making answer . *.^

Comment: @Henry If later find the method to change current location of simulator, i will share here.

Comment: but going back to question what should be final uri that i could deploy to driver's android phone so where starting point is his current location, then some defined staticly waypoints and destination. Can you give final uri so i would test in on real phone.

Comment: @Henry The sample test uri is in answer but need your api data. You also can modify the data of destination and waypoints yourself,then can test.The official document (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) explain how to set parameters.

Comment: @Henry I have found the way to change location of simulator.I will update in answer.

Comment: I've updated it in settings and put my current location lang and att then using your test uri and put some destination point. I still see "No route found" ehh... Can we shortly talk in chat?

Comment: @Yeah, but I do not know how to start a chat In SO.Or you can show your uri , I will check it.

Comment: I finally set current position in emulator - i just mixed long and latt - now its ok. I have two additional questions: 1) When i use uri is it true when no google maps installed on device it will be opened in browser and if it is then it will open google map app? 2) Is it possible to get distance in km from uri?

Comment: @Henry First question, although uri can correcttly navigation on PC's browser，but it need to be tested in mobile.Second question,from the perspective of Google Docs, at least it is impossible to get the distance now.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
String mapsUrl = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=48.8276261,2.3350114&destination=48.8476794,2.340595&waypoints=48.8550395,2.300022|48.8417122,2.3028844&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mapsUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Where

`origin` is your starting point
`destination` is your ending point
`waypoints` is your stops

you should add `waypoint` with using `|`

example: `waypoints=48.8550395,2.300022|48.8417122,2.3028844`

You can also add `travelmode` to specify travel mode

These are travel modes that you can use: `driving`,`bicycling`,`transit`,`walking`

This will open Google Maps in driving mode

Comment: i still no have start navigate button but only preview button. Can origin be set automaticly by my current position?

Comment: any feedback Pacyn?

Comment: @Henry You should manually get your location coordinates, and use add it to your origin. Can you show your code where you get your location

Comment: What do you mean by manually? All points besides origin will come from database but origin should be created automaticly based on current location of driver. Means when driver open my app i will construct entire link data from database like destination/waypoints but origin should be somehow defined automaticly so i should be able to say in code something like origin = GetCurrentLocation() and this paste this to origin=<GetCurrentLocation()>. So not manually.

Comment: @Henry So how you get current location of a driver ? can you show us code?

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to get this value for origin field. You propose to make staticly : origin=48.8276261,2.3350114 i want something like: origin=GetCurrent(),GetCurrent(). So i need GetCurrent to get current 'right now' current location where driver starts application

Comment: @Henry you can put in origin what you want, but you should look about `LocationManager` and how to get current location of user.